# How to check if there is directory already exists or not in databricks

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

How do I check if there is already exists or not in databricks

```
dir = "/mnt/published/omega/omega_output"
if(dbutils.fs.exists(dir)):
 print("dir exists")
else:
 print("dir does not exists")
```

This code throws me error as

```
'FSHandler' object has no attribute 'exists'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `exists` function in the `dbutils.fs`. There are few approaches to solve this:

1. Use local file API - it will work only with mounted resources. You need to append `/dbfs` to the path:

```py
import os
dir = '/mnt/....'
if os.path.exists(f"/dbfs{dir}"):
  ....
```

2. Use Hadoop file API - it will work with `dbfs:/`, `abfss:/`, ...

```py
URI           = sc._gateway.jvm.java.net.URI
Path          = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
FileSystem    = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
Configuration = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration

dir = "..."
fs = FileSystem.get(URI(dir), Configuration())

if fs.exists(Path(dir)):
  ...
```

3. Try to list a path, and catch exception when file doesn't exist or not accessible. Main problem - you can't distinguish between files/directories that  doesn't exist and files/directories to which you don't have access permissions:

```py
def file_exists(dir):
  try:
    dbutils.fs.ls(dir)
  except:
    return False  
  return True
```